# Regexp with '&' char using preg_replace

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to parse URLs containing `&` with `preg_replace`.

```
$content = preg_replace('#https?://[a-z0-9._/\?=&-]+#i', '<a href="$0" target="_blank">$0</a>', $content);
```

But I use it for user comments, so I'm also using htmlspecialchars() function to prevent XSS.

```
function formatContributionContent($content)
{
    $content = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($content));

    // Regexp for mails
    $content = preg_replace('#[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._&-]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,4}#', '<a href="mailto:$0">$0</a>', $content);

    // Regexp for urls
    $content = preg_replace('#https?://[a-z0-9._/\?=&-]+#i', '<a href="$0" target="_blank">$0</a>', $content);

    var_dump($content);
}

formatContributionContent('https://openclassrooms.com/index.php?page=3&skin=blue');
```

And htmlspecialchars transforms `&` into `"&amp;"` so my regexp produce a wrong result. Indeed, with the following URL.

```
http://www.siteduzero.com/index.php?page=3&skin=blue
```

I obtain `;`

```
<a href="https://openclassrooms.com/index.php?page=3&amp" target="_blank">https://openclassrooms.com/index.php?page=3&amp</a>;skin=blue
```

Comment: You cannot expect your regular expression to somehow magically heal content you modified before handing it over. Instead you would _first_ have to make your replacements and _then_ maybe use the `htmlspecialchars()` method to output the result. But probably you would have to apply it to the separate parts of that URL, not to the whole URL, since it would obviously turn the URL into its readable notation instead of rendering it in a usable way. So your whole approach won't work. You'd have to split that URL first and handle the tokens separately.

Comment: I would like to transform urls into links in user comments.

Comment: Assuming that you don't want any HTML tag from user input to be rendered, you need to use regex to pick out the positions of the emails and links, then use it to tokenize the input. Whatever not email or link will be entity-escaped, email and links are put into anchors, then we merge them together. (What I say here is an elaboration on what arkascha said)

Answer (score 1):

You can add ";" in the list of characters matched by your regexp, like this :

```
$content = preg_replace('#https?://[a-z0-9._/\?=&;-]+#i', '<a href="$0" target="_blank">$0</a>', $content);
```

This way, `"&"` characters are transformed in `"&amp;"` by htmlspecialchars, but your regexp can find the whole url.

Comment: Although this solves OP's problem it creates another one: using this regex a website such as this ``https://;.com`` is valid.

Comment: Thanks ! :) It looks so ridiculous. ^^"

Comment: @Pedro Pinheiro : That's true, but the original regex didn't validate the url neither, and a url like `https://.com` was already valid.

Comment: For the moment i wasn't trying to have a url validator, but just using preg_replace with htmlspecialchars.

Comment: This is a terrible solution. You are processing a HTML-escaped string with a regex which is not aware of HTML-escaped syntax